# Translating statements into Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, logic-translation

I am facing problem in translating these statements to logic statements.

1. Some horses are gentle only if they have been well trained.
2. Some horses are gentle if they have been well trained.

I am not able to differentiate the above two statements.

$Hx$: $x$ is a horse.
$Gx$: $x$ is gentle. 
$Tx$: $x$ has been well trained.

I translated the first statement as $\exists x (Hx\rightarrow (Tx \rightarrow Gx))$.

Comment: Isn't the first one an "if and only if"?

Comment: @Anon Anon Do you know there's a difference between "A if B" and "A only if B"?

Comment: yes. Is my first answer correct ?

Comment: @GitGud Do you mean there is no difference between statement 1 and this statement : "Some horses are gentle if only if they have been well trained."

Comment: @Anonymous: "$p$ only if $q$" is a perfectly cromulent construct meaning "$p\to q$."

Answer (score 3):

Note the following:

- "$p$ only if $q$" means $p\to q$.
- "$p$ if $q$" means $p\leftarrow q$, more commonly denoted $q\to p$.
- "Some foo are bar" means that there exists one or more $x$ such that $x$ is a foo that is bar, i.e., such that $x$ is both foo *and* bar.

With these in mind, it should hopefully be clear that the statements you've supplied can be translated as:

1. $\exists x(Hx \land (Gx \to Tx))$
2. $\exists x(Hx \land (Tx \to Gx))$

Comment: Your distinction between "$p$ only if $q$" and "$p$ if $q$" is wrong. I can't see how "only" would make any difference in the "direction" of implication. At most it can make "$\leftrightarrow$" from "$\rightarrow$".

Comment: @m.woj: No, $\leftrightarrow$ is conventionally pronounced as "if and only if" exactly _because_ "if" expresses implication in one direction and "only if" expresses implication in the other direction. The idiom would perhaps have been clearer if it had been "only when" instead of "only if", but jwodder has the established semantics completely right.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Could you please provide any link/website supporting your claim that ' "p if q" means p←q, more commonly denoted q→p.'

Comment: @AnonAnon: That's jwodder's claim not, not mine. I would notate it $q\to p$ from the beginning.